# Possible to Do Oauth 2 on Windows Phone 7 without and internal browser?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-api, oauth-2.0

I want to use some apis from google api. However to get at private data I need to use an oAuth v2.

From what I seen from tutorials of people using oAuth(for foursquare) is that they use an internal browser. I am wondering if there is

a) a way to by pass this and do some other way

b) or how can I make the internal browser look semi nice.

What I mean by option "b" is that when a user would go into my application they would see the internal browser loaded with Google login. After they authenticate I get short lived token to then access their private data.

To me this mean every time a user logs into my application they have to see that ugly internal browser. Even if I set the Google authentication to one time(after they log in for the first time) I still need to show them the internal browser again the next time to get a new token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** show a web browser for OAuth authentication. It is a requirement for OAuth in general.